# Instructing the compiler about the likeliness of a loop condition

Tags: optimization, gcc, macros, linux-kernel

In the Linux kernel, there are the **likely** and **unlikely** macros to instruct the compiler about the expected value of an if condition. Is there a similar way to do so in a while loop? can the likely/unlikely macros be used in the while loop?

Does something like:

```
while(unlikely( /*some boolean check*/)){
   ...
}
```

has the intended effect?

Comment: If `/* some boolean check*/` is unlikely, that means the number of iterations of the `while` loop is most likely to be 0. Is that what you intend? Usually a loop automatically tells the compiler the condition is likely.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey yes, that's my intent. My example is a while loop that right shifts bits in order to reduce significant bits if the number is too large and I expect this to be a uncommon scenario.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I would study the generated asm. If it's not what you want, maybe putting an if-statement around the loop would convince it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

likely and unlikely are associated with tests. You can use them with while and ifs.

Your code will have the intended effect.

Comment: Do you know any reference about it?

Comment: They will boil down to the GCC function `__builtin_expect`. You can read about that [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).